# Problems in adding collection to list with list.Add

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, generics

```
 private List<T> ParsePolicyDetails<T>(List<HouseHoldview> lsthousehold)
    {
        List<T> lstPolicyInfo = new List<T>();

        var checkInHouseHold = from c in lsthousehold
                               where c.PolicyDetail.Any(p => p.LineOfBusiness.Trim().ToUpper() == "A" && p.PolicySourceSystem.ToUpper().Trim() != "PLCS"
                                   && p.PolicySourceSystem.ToUpper().Trim() != "APS"
                                   && p.PolicySourceSystem.ToUpper().Trim() != "FOREMOST")
                               select c.PolicyDetail;

        foreach (var policies in checkInHouseHold)
        {
            var chek=policies.Where(p => p.LineOfBusiness.Trim().ToUpper() == "A" && p.PolicySourceSystem.ToUpper().Trim() != "PLCS"
                                     && p.PolicySourceSystem.ToUpper().Trim() != "APS"
                                     && p.PolicySourceSystem.ToUpper().Trim() != "FOREMOST" && p.LineOfBusiness.ToUpper().Trim() == "A");
            lstPolicyInfo.Add(chek);
        }
        return lstPolicyInfo;
    }
```

Looks like very simple code but giving error. As chek is not of type T how to handle this

Error is The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add()

Comment: Please add a language tag, this looks like C#

Comment: 1) You're trying to add a sequence (the result of calling `Where`) to a list. That sounds like a bad idea. 2) It doesn't look like this should be generic at all. 3) "but giving error" is never enough information - **always** say what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method isn't generic; you want to replace

- `List<T>` with `List<WhateverTypeHouseHoldview.PolicyDetailIs>`
- `ParsePolicyDetails<T>` with `ParsePolicyDetails`
- `lstPolicyInfo.Add` with `lstPolicyInfo.AddRange`

Comment: It worked could you please tell me briefly what does AddRange does

Comment: `Add` only adds a single item to a list; `AddRange` takes a _range_ of items and adds them _all_ to the list. Thus, as `chek` is a range of items (it's the result of a LINQ query), you need to use `AddRange` rather than `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of var may be confusing matters.

Try changing them to their actual types and this may help you understand what is going on.

Difficult to tell without seeing how the rest of the class/s are set up.